# Multidimensional JSON to javascript array for highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Following is JSON notation returned by Response::json() function from Laravel:

```
{
    "area":["zone1","zone2","zone3"],
    "target":["7.91","4.95","2.95"],
    "sales":["12.35","6.99","4.13"]
}
```

How can i get 'area' as category, target and sales as series for highcharts(column) using javascript?

For example, how can i get following:

```
 var cat=['zone1','zone2', 'zone3'];
 var series1=[7.91, 4.95,2.95];
 var series2=[12.35,6.99,4.13];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. If you are using pure javascript you can do something like

```
cat = new Array();
series1 = new Array();
series2 = new Array();
for (var value in data["area"])
{
    cat.push(data["area"][value]);
}

for (var value in data["target"])
{
    series1.push(data["target"][value]);
}

for (var value in data["sales"])
{
    series2.push(data["sales"][value]);
}
```

Or if you want a solution using `jQuery` then you can do something like:

```
var cat = $.map(data["area"], function(value,key) { return value; });
var series1 = $.map(data["target"], function(value,key) { return value; });
var series2 = $.map(data["sales"], function(value,key) { return value; });
```

Both solutions will give you an output of:

```
["zone1", "zone2", "zone3"]
["7.91", "4.95", "2.95"]
["12.35", "6.99", "4.13"]
```

## Edit

So the data I used was the same JSON object that you provided where every value is a string, but your desired output (and the output Highcharts will want) is the series data in Numeric form so you will need to take that into account.

Comment: Easiest is jQuery and perfect solution. Better than .each() and for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can help you.

```
var data = {
  "area":["zone1","zone2","zone3"],
  "target":["7.91","4.95","2.95"],
  "sales":["12.35","6.99","4.13"]
};

var cat = data.area;
var series1 = data.target;
var series2 = data.sales;
```